# How to refactor procedural start-up code?

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I have a class (Android Activity) which handles start-up of my application. The application has some pretty complex start-up rules. Right now it looks like a bunch of spaghetti and I'm looking for strategies for refactoring it.

It's honestly such a mess I'm having problems hacking it down to provides pseudo code. In general there are some rules for start-up that are basically codified in logic:

Steps:

1. Check for error on last exit and flush local cache if necessary
2. Download settings file
3. Parse settings and save settings to local native format
4. Using the values in settings, do a bunch of 'house keeping'
5. Using a value in settings, download core data component A
6. Parse component A and load up local cache

During this logic, its also updating the user interface. All of this is handled in a zig-zagging, single monolithic class. Its very long, its got a bunch of dependencies, the logic is very hard to follow and it seems to touch way too many parts of the application.

Is there a strategy or framework that can be used to break up procedural start-up code?

Comment: Have you tried extracting stuff out to a class and inject that class using something like Roboguice?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  Based on your steps, I see various different "concerns":

1. Reading and saving settings.
2. Downloading settings and components (not sure what a "component" is here) from the server.
3. Reading and instantiating components.
4. Flush and read cache.
5. Housekeeping (not really sure what this all entails).
6. UI updates (not really sure what this requires either).

You might try splitting up the code into various objects along the lines of the above, for example:

1. SettingsReader
2. ServerCommunicationManager (?)
3. ComponentReader
4. Cache

Not sure about 5 and 6, since I don't have much to go on there.

Regarding frameworks, well, there are various ones such as the previously mentioned Roboguice, that can help with dependency injection.  Those may come in handy, or it may be easier just to do this by hand.  I think that before you consider dependency injection, though, you need to untangle the code.  All that dependency injection frameworks do is to initialize your objects for you -- you have to make sure that the objects make sense first.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply. I guess I'm kinda wondering if there is some strategy to wrapping procedural rules and turning them into objects?

Comment: Sure.  What I would do is to look at the types of things that the procedures are dealing with.  For example, you listed a bunch of things in the form "verb the noun" ("flush the cache", "download the settings", etc.).  Each of your [nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) is a class: hence Cache, Settings, etc.  Sometimes you then have to apply a layer of abstraction and combine functionality -- for example, you may not want your Settings directly downloading itself (or maybe you do).  Perhaps there's some common code that handles all downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more details, the only suggestion that I can think of is to group the various steps behind well structured functions which do one thing and one thing only.

Your 6 steps look to be a good start for the 6 functions your init function should have. If #2 was synchronous (I doubt it), I would merge #2, #3 into a `getSettings` function.